# Combine XML Parameters

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, xquery

I need Some XML Query Help
I would like to know How I con Combine data from Multiple Rows into One Row
For My issue:( Current Query)

```
SELECT 
    Name = Paravalue.value('Name[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)'),
    Value = Paravalue.value('Value[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)')
FROM (
        SELECT CONVERT(XML,Parameters) as ParameterXML FROM ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions WHERE SubscriptionID = 'Test'
     ) a
CROSS APPLY ParameterXML.nodes('/ParameterValues/ParameterValue') p ( Paravalue )
```

Results  in:

```
  Name                   Value
1 IncludeNotSubmitted    True
2 EndDate                NULL
3 StartDate              NULL
```

The Results I desire are:

```
  Parameter Values               
1 IncludeNotSubmitted: True  EndDate: NULL StartDate: NULL
```

Can any one point me in the right direction?

January 09 Edit :
Miss the inclusion of the actual XML

```
<ParameterValues>
<ParameterValue>
<Name>IncludeNotSubmitted</Name>
<Value>True</Value>
</ParameterValue>
<ParameterValue>
<Name>EndDate</Name>
</ParameterValue>
<ParameterValue>
<Name>StartDate</Name
</ParameterValue>
</ParameterValues>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it in a single query, by using a *Common Table Expression* and *FOR XML PATH*:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        Name = Paravalue.value('@Name[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)'),
        Value = Paravalue.value('@Value[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)'),
        SubscriptionID
    FROM (
            SELECT CONVERT(XML,[Parameters]) as ParameterXML, SubscriptionID FROM ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions WHERE SubscriptionID = 'Test'
         ) a
    CROSS APPLY ParameterXML.nodes('/ParameterValues/ParameterValue') p ( Paravalue )
)
SELECT  STUFF((select ', ' + Name + ': ' + value as [text()]
        FROM cte xt
        WHERE xt.SubscriptionID = t.SubscriptionID
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM cte t
GROUP BY SubscriptionID
```

I'm assuming your XML data on *Parameters* field looks like this:

```
<ParameterValues>
    <ParameterValue Name="IncludeNotSubmitted" Value="True" />
    <ParameterValue Name="StartDate" Value="null" />
    <ParameterValue Name="EndDate" Value="null" />
</ParameterValues>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The XML data is not exactly what you have assumed. I have added the XML data on the original post. I am very close. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to accomplish this in a single query? If not, you could insert the results of your xml query into a table valued variable and then populate a variable with all the rows of the table valued variable like so:

```
--make a table valued variable
declare @sample table (
    Id int identity(1,1),
    Name varchar(50),
    Value varchar(50)
)

--put some test data in it
--here you would select using you xml query from your post
insert @sample (Name, Value)
select 'IncludeNotSubmitted', 'True'
union all
select 'EndDate', null
union all
select 'StartDate', null

--we're going to store the combined values in this variable
declare @combinedString varchar(max) = ''
select @combinedString = @combinedString + Name + ':' + isnull(Value, 'NULL') + '   ' 
from @sample

select @combinedString

--results:
-- IncludeNotSubmitted:True   EndDate:NULL   StartDate:NULL
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to do this in a Single query but this does give me an alternative that may suit my needs. Thank you!.